# Should I use Lua?

Tags: javascript, lua

I am going to work on my new project where client has demanded to use **'Lua'** if possible, I have never used it before and by searching on it I found it is fast compare to javascript and getting popular nowadays.

As I am very confused I had never use it before so I want to know something

- Is it really better(in terms of performance and use) then javascript?
- Will I get enough resources(because I don't want to move over after starting development due to lack of resources or it becomes hard to me develop)?
- Will it needed anything other than C compiler to run?

Please guys it is really important to know about such thing before starting. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's "getting popular" for at least a decade already, not recently. Yes it is faster, yes it is leaner, yes, you only need C compiler.

Comment: Can you give more details on the project? It really depends on what you want to build.

Comment: Yes, for what project you're going to use `Lua`, it is popular long time ago amongst gamedevs, for example, as scripting tool e.g. it was outsourced to users (players) to design `AI` of their ingame pets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're writing a standalone application in C or C++, and you're looking for a language to enable people to extend that application by embedding another language. That's pretty much Lua's territory.

Lua's strong point is that it's very easy to embed in your (C) application. It compiles quickly, it's tiny, licensing is liberal and using C functions from Lua is relatively easy. Standard Lua has enough performance for most things you'd use a language like this for; if you need more raw speed you could look into [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/), the JIT-compiler for Lua.

As for your questions:

- LuaJIT will probably be pretty much as fast as you can get for a dynamic language. Lua is used in games (Sim City, Far Cry, World of Warcraft), where performance is very important.
- If by 'resources' you mean documentation: sure. Lua is a very simple language, much simpler than JavaScript; the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html) should help you get started with the language itself, [the wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua) is tasty for tips about the embedding process. [This article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/264) has an example you can copy/paste.
- Lua pretty much runs everywhere a C program will run. It doesn't even need an operating system, and it doesn't depend on anything at runtime if you bundle it correctly.

Embedding a full JavaScript environment in your application, and interfacing your application to the JS environment, can be a lot of work (even though Google's V8 engine has some functionality to help you; see [here](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed)).